# "No resolved dependencies found when searching for the jacoco version." when executing gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I have recently updated my android project to gradle 2.8. 
Since then I am getting this message in the build log:

```
$ ./gradlew clean
No resolved dependencies found when searching for the jacoco version.
No resolved dependencies found when searching for the jacoco version.
[ant:exec] Result: 1
[...]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8.922 secs
```

The build appears to finish correctly, but this message becomes quite annoying.

What does it mean and how can I resolve it?

**EDIT: add build.gradle**

This is the build.gradle of the lowest-level module:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` so we can see what is failing

Comment: Seems like this is a multi module project. What's the output of `./gradlew projects`

Comment: Did you recently upgrade gradle-android plugin version? I started seeing this when upgrading to android tools 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is letting you know that the build system doesn't know what version of `jacoco` to use.

You must specify the version to the android configuration block.

```
android {
    // ...
    jacoco {
        version = '0.7.3.201502191951'
    }
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is, why jacoco comes up at all. I have not specified it anywhere and I don't want to use it at this point. Is it now on by default?

Comment: It's not on by default as far as I know.  Not sure where this is coming from if your not trying to do coverage reports